# How to override code to use jersey and Jax-RS jars available in WEB-INF\lib?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, weblogic, jdeveloper

Server: Weblogic  10.3.6.0

IDE: JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

I created a java restful web-service following [this blog](http://markchensblog.blogspot.in/2014/05/develop-and-deploy-jersey-restful.html). As stated in blog, I added two jars: javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar and jersey-bundle-1.9.jar as library in the project. The deployment went fine and the url worked.

Now, I included these two jars in project as jars and not as libraries. I executed the main method to test and deployed the project war file which went fine. But after deployment, when I am calling the rest url, I am getting error as:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

The web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

weblogic.xml is:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
  <library-ref>
    <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
    <specification-version>1.1</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>1.9</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
  </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Not sure, if there is an issue with web.xml and weblogic.xml which should be changed if I want to redirect code to jars present in project.

I have read about `<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>` in weblogic.xml ([Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/using_3rd_party_jdbc_jar)) but, I am unable to understand the changes to be made in web.xml file.

How can I force my application to use jersey and jax-rs jars in WEB-INF/lib folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all the jars from lib folder and imported all jars downloaded from [Jersey 1.19 ZIP bundle](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). I read [javarevisited blog](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2016/02/javalangclassnotfoundexception-com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-solution.html) and made the following changes in web.xml and weblogic.xml

web.xml :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <display-name>JerseyServer</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.oracle.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

weblogic.xml :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I was able to deploy and call the rest url successfully.

Note: I tried with [Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) too. It worked fine on my local server. But the remote weblogic server was not compatible with compiled class version. The error while deploying was: 'org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer : unsupported classversion 51.0'

Answer (score 0):

Mine work with this code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Register resources and providers -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.jersey.series.upload.download.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Comment: While the code you've provided may include the answer to the OP's problem - the post is not very useful without an explanation of how you've solved their issue.